# how to make changes in .env file without reloading server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I am using a form from front end to change my .env file variable values, after changing the values, changes are being saved in my env file, but its not reflecting on my laravel application, after restarting my server its reflecting on my website, but i cant do this if its in live server, I tried  PHP artisan config:clear and PHP artisan cache:clear but none of its working.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this without restarting server.

I am trying to change these values in .env
HTTP_HOST=http://
SFTP_HOST=10.10.10.64

Comment: Is your server running OpCache? If so, check out this package at https://github.com/appstract/laravel-opcache to clear it when making changes.  Also, if you are running queue workers in daemon mode, they must be restarted to reflect any changes to the app.

Comment: Did @matticustard's comment help or are you still experiencing the issue? If so, would you be able to provide a bit more information about your set up i.e. Laravel version, server and version, and if you have any caching enabled, and how you're retrieving the env value.

Comment: I don't know the process that matticustard told, my laravel version is 5.5 and server I don't exactly the version, I need to check, I am editing and retrieving .env file by taking a reference from a tutorial, it's not a package. I tried to do the same functionality at my home laptop, it is working fine, without restarting the server, but not working at my office server